# Convertion of long in Windows store application

Tags: windows-store-apps, type-conversion

I am writing a windows 8 store application and have the following problem:
I have a textblock binded to a long property of an object.
The long value is 123456789, however, on the screen i only see the char 1.
How can i solve this, and why the convertion to string doesn't work like it should?

Comment: Please post your code as my code is working. I tried with largest `long` value [9223372036854775807](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue.aspx).

Comment: I forget to say that the textblock is in a DataTemplate. I can see all other properties i wrote in my DataTemplate like double and int well, but not the long property i'm binding to. The template is written in a GridView.

Comment: Better you update your question with your "tried" code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me if it works for you or not.

XAML

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:myVm />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding col}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="20" FontSize="20" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

myVm.cs

```
public class myVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public myVm()
    {
        col.Add(long.MaxValue);
        col.Add(long.MaxValue);
        col.Add(long.MaxValue);
        col.Add(long.MaxValue);
        col.Add(long.MaxValue);
        col.Add(long.MaxValue);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<long> _col = new ObservableCollection<long>();
    public ObservableCollection<long> col
    {
        get { return _col; }
        set
        {
            _col = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("col");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what went wrong in my app. The object I bounded to had an attribute of [Key] and that why it become to int automatically.